# Xamarin iOS Splash Screen build from Windows Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to change my app's splash screen into a custom image, I haven't found a solution that solved it for me ... I will be more than happy if someone will be able to solve it.
Thanks

**I'm using Xamarin iOS on Windows Visual Studio**

Comment: have you tried following the official docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=macos

Comment: Hi Jason, as written in this article, "The iOS Designer was deprecated in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8" ...
Thanks  ..

Comment: yes, and there is a link there "Designing user interfaces with Xcode"

Comment: That's the point, my Mac won't hold Xcode well and that's why I will be really happy if anyone knows a way to change the splash screen on windows ..

Comment: AFAIK the best way (and possibly only) is to use XCode

Comment: Gernerally, have to use Xcode, but if the splash is simple as just one logo image, probably can copy some code and paste to the storyboard file via text editor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider adding a Page to your Forms project as a Splash Page.

like

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage =   new SplashPage();
    }
```

Then add a delay in SplashPage to jump to MainPage.

```
public  SplashPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Task.Run(async ()=> { 
            
            await Task.Delay(3000);

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> { App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();});  

        });       
      
    }
```